# Javascript: Form Validation - Remove error messages from corrected fields

Tags: javascript, forms

when I submit a form with errors (for example user has not completed a required field) I am able to display the error messages. However, If I correct one of the fields and submit again BOTH error messages remain.

The errors only go when ALL fields are correctly filled in.

What have I done wrong?

If i correct a field and click submit I eant the error message for the corrected field to go away and only the remining incorrect fields to have error messages.

**HTML:**

```
   <form id="frm1">
   <fieldset id="controls">
    <div>
      <label for="firstname">First Name: </label>
       <input type="text" id="firstname">
        <span id="errFname" class="errmsg">&#42 You must enter a first name</span>
    </div>
    <div>
       <label for="lastname">Last Name: </label>
       <input type="text" id="lastname">
        <span id="errLname" class="errmsg">&#42 You must enter a first name</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
    </fieldset>
   </form>
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
function checkForm(){



    document.getElementById("frm1").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {

        var errors = [];


        //Validate first name: Required, Alphabetic (no numbers)
        if(document.getElementById("firstname").value === "") {

            document.getElementById("errFname").style.display = "inline";
            document.getElementById("firstname").focus();

            errors.push("required");

        }//close if


        var alphaRegEx = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;;
        var alphafname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
        var alphalname = document.getElementById("lastname").value;

        //check if first name has any digits
        if (!alphaRegEx.test(alphafname)){

            document.getElementById("errFname").style.display = "inline";
            document.getElementById("firstname").value="";
            document.getElementById("firstname").focus();

            errors.push("numeric");


        }//close if

        //check if last name has any digits
        if (!alphaRegEx.test(alphalname)){

            document.getElementById("errLname").style.display = "inline";
            document.getElementById("lastname").value="";
            document.getElementById("lastname").focus();

            errors.push("numeric");


        }//close if

        //If you want, you can do something with your errors, if not, just return
        if (errors.length > 0) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    });//close function



}//close function (checkForm)


window.onload=checkForm;
```

Comment: Your `alphaRegEx` is wrong, it validates only first symbol, regex should be `/^[a-zA-Z]+$/`

Comment: You really need to stop comment the closing braces with "close if", "close function" etc. as they are useless.

Answer (score 2):

You must first clear all the errors when the `checkForm` is called.

```
function checkForm() {
    clearErrors();

    Rest functionality same...
}

function clearErrors() {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(
        document.getElementsByClassName("errmsg"),
        function(el) { el.style.display = "none"; }
    );
}
```

This will clear all the errors first and then display only those errors which have not yet been resolved.

Comment: Actually that seems to prevent the error messages all together.

Comment: No it will not, what it will do is 1) Remove all messages, 2) Check individual conditions and display error messages as applicable.

Comment: Your idea was almost correct, wouldn't work ByClassName .. had to call each one by ID. And it had to go after the event listener: 
    document.getElementById("frm1").addEventListener("submit", function(e) { document.getElementById("errFname").style.display = 'none';   It works now.

Comment: It should have worked usin class ="errmsg" as well, since all the spans have that class.

Comment: @MauriceGreenland Nikhil's idea is correct, however `getElementsByClassName` returns an array object, which needs to be looped. I submitted an edit to his answer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was set each error message display property to 'none' before going through the validation.

```
function checkForm() {

        //Event listener
        document.getElementById("contactForm").addEventListener("submit", function(prevent) {

//Set display property for inline error messages to none
            document.getElementById("errFname").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("errLname").style.display = 'none';

//Rest of code remains the same...
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` is better because in your answer you are tightly coupling to ids, if you add another N fields you'd need to modify your javascript as well